# update elasticsearch template without override it

Tags: elasticsearch

i have an existing template and i tried to update only the number of shards in it.

When doing:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_template/my_template -d '{"template" : "my_template", "settings" : {"number_of_shards":"3"}}'
```

it is override all my other settings and mappings.

i looked into the `update api` but it seems that its only for documents.

**So must i read the template and then write it back ?**

Also, can i accomplish that using the `order` in templates?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `POST` a template it will overwrite the previous template if such existed. So yes, you will have to first `GET` the template, make your adjustments and then `POST` it. The `order` attribute is to determine how the merge will be performed **if two templates are defined for the same index**, not the case you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks! using `PUT` also didn't help. what will happen if i will define another template with higher order but with settings => # of shards = 3 ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, index templates will apply to NEW indexes only, not for previously created ones. Do you want to update the settings of a currently existing index? You can do that, but you'll have to use the `/_settings` endpoint (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) and also you cannot change the number of shards after you've inserted documents into an index, so if that's the setting you're trying to change you'll have to delete and recreate the index.

Comment: i know i can't update the number of shards for an existing index. i would like to somehow change a template without reading it before. (i.e. update) . i was wonder if using the `order` in templates can make this effect.

Comment: 0

is it possible to restore the index template config to the previous value as it is overridden now?

Comment: How to restore the previous value of index template in elastic search which got overrided by PUT request ?